# Как получить чисто значение переменной на php через $b = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('a'));</script>";?

Tags: javascript, php

Долго мучаюсь над проблемой:
Записываю слово "Тест" в localstorage, потом получаю его обратно в переменной $b, но оно тянется все вместе со скриптом. var_dump() пишет что это разные переменные.

```
<?php
$a = 'Тест';
?>
<!--Запись в localstorage-->
<script>
localStorage.setItem('a', '<?php echo $a; ?>'); 
</script>

<?php //Получаем с localestorage
$b = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('a'));</script>";
var_dump($a); echo ('|'); var_dump($b); //Получаем string(8) "Тест" |string(59) "Тест"
?>
```

Какие есть варианты чтобы записать в js а получить в php в том же виде? Чтобы я мог их сравнивать? На выходе получаю два разных слова "Тест"

Comment: Подсказка - 59 это длина строки `<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('a'));</script>`. Поэтому разберись __еще раз__ в чем отличие клиента от сервера.

Comment: И вот статья которая добавит ясности http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Comment: Спасибо! Читаю и пытаюсь все переосмыслить.)

Answer (score 2):

> //Получаем с localestorage

**localStorage в PHP нету! PHP это бекенд, localStorage это фронтенд**

> Какие есть варианты чтобы записать в js а получить в php в том же
> виде?

cookies, query string, post-data

Comment: Это да, но важно разобраться в этом. Из php я же могу получить данные из localStorage? Могу. Вопрос в том как их получить в том же размере что и записал? Сейчас успешно получаю оба слова "Тест" но они разных размеров. И на них не работает условие "==" в php

Comment: Вы видимо путаете БД на сервере и хранилище в браузере у посетителя сайта. Как, по вашему, сервер получит доступ к тому что записано в браузере в localStorage? PHP работает на сервере и отдаёт результаты посетителю, а не наоборот. Вам правильно написали про cookies, query string и form data - эти данные посетитель может передать серверу при открытии страницы.

Comment: @Максим я же написал, что в PHP нету localStorage. Вы заметили слово local, что означает локальное, т.е. на стороне пользователя

Comment: Спасибо, понял ну как тогда поступить? Максимальный размер файла cookie составляет 4 КБ... и 20 файлов. всего лишь. У меня задача распарсить xml файл (допустим 1000 товаров), при повторном запуске php парсера выводить надпись изменились ли данные узла. Т.е. надо куда то записать данные после разбора xml и при следующем разборе их сравнить. localStorage выбрал потому что там до 5 мб можно писать вроде как подходит. Через document.write() я могу выполнять любой скрипт на стороне браузера. БД у меня нет, по этому вариант с Storage.setItem() Storage.getItem() вроде оптимально было бы?

Comment: не пойму что с чем Вы сравнивать собрались, но если очень жмет, то можете данные с localStorage конвертнуть в json и передать на сервер, а там уже декодировать и сравнивать с чем-то

Comment: Сравниваю прошлый прайс с предыдущим и вывожу надпись какая строка обновилась). Сейчас ниже выложу то до чего дошел с использованием $_SESSION (так работает), надеюсь так будет понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Так сравниваю данные прошлой выгрузки с данными текущей.
Сравниваются 4 переменные $surname,$first_name,$phone,$tin
И выводится надпись обновлено/не обновлено возле каждого пункта.
Значения предыдущих полей ведется в сесиию $_SESSION['t1']
Значения новых мы получаем напрямую с файла.
И в конце их ставниваем предыдущие с новыми.

```
<?php 

session_start(); //Инициализируем сессию только один раз за скрипт
//unset($_SESSION['t1']); //Для очистки
if (!isset($_SESSION['t1'])) { //Если сессия таблицы 1 не определена тогда запишем значения      

$_SESSION['t1'] = array($surname,$first_name,$phone,$tin);
//Назначаем чтобы при первом запуске сравнивалка работала
$a = $_SESSION['t1'][0];
$b = $_SESSION['t1'][1];
$c = $_SESSION['t1'][2];
$d = $_SESSION['t1'][3];

echo ('Сессия t1 не существует! Записали в нее данные');

} else { //Если опредена тогда назначим текущее значение xml файла
$a = $_SESSION['t1'][0];
$b = $_SESSION['t1'][1];
$c = $_SESSION['t1'][2];
$d = $_SESSION['t1'][3];
} 

echo ('<ul>');
if ($a == $surname ) {echo ('<li>Не обновлено</li>');} else {echo ('<li>Обновлено</li>');}
if ($b == $first_name ) {echo ('<li>Не обновлено</li>');} else {echo ('<li>Обновлено</li>');}
if ($c == $phone ) {echo ('<li>Не обновлено</li>');} else {echo ('<li>Обновлено</li>');}
if ($d == $tin ) {echo ('<li>Не обновлено</li>');} else {echo ('<li>Обновлено</li>');}
echo ('</ul>');

echo ('Предыдущие данные: ');
print_r($_SESSION['t1']);

echo ('<hr>Новые данные: ');
$news = array($surname, $first_name,$phone, $tin);
print_r($news);

?>
```